# Pytest side effect: how to give extra arguments and keep the method arguments?

Tags: python, pytest, side-effects, pytest-mock

I'm trying to test a method which has a call to another one inside it:

```py
def my_method(id: int) -> List[Aat]:
    query_parameter: str = my_second_method(name="parameter_name")
    another_query_parameter: str = my_second_method(name="another_parameter_name")
```

Then, I need to give a side effect to "my_second_method" considering its own arguments and a list which I would pass to the side_effect function. Before considering this list, my code would be like this:

```py
def test_my_method(mocker):
    valid_values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    invalid_values = list(filter(lambda l: l not in valid_programs, list(string.ascii_uppercase)))
        
    for letter in invalid_values:
        query_string_mock.current_event.get_query_string_value.side_effect = side_effect
        response = my_package.my_method(MagicMock())
        assert ...

def side_effect(*args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs["name"] == "parameter_name":
        return ...
    elif kwargs["name"] == "another_parameter_name":
        return ...
```

How can I give to my side_effect function an extra argument and to keep the original arguments of "my_second_method"?

```py
def side_effect(extra_argument, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs["name"] == "parameter_name":
        return extra_argument
    elif kwargs["name"] == "another_parameter_name":
        return ...
```

The code above is not working because if I do like this, the original arguments are lost. That means, *kwargs* is empty. Could you help me on this, please?

Thank you!